# How do I check if a string is included in the results for a bash command?

Tags: bash, shell

In a bash script, I have a line approximately like so - which returns a multi-line response:

```
FILE_LIST = $(find some/path -type f )
```

I'd like to check whether the response contains a particular string, for example:

```
IF  not ("filename" in FILE_LIST)
```

How do I perform this kind of test inside a bash script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if echo "$FILE_LIST" |tr ' ' '\n' |grep -q "filename"
```

Or directly:

```
if find some/path -type f | grep -q "filename"
```

Your FILE_LIST won't work for files with spaces though.

Comment: it won't find files with spaces in it? How do I fix that?